# Trying to find the default selection but values returned in console are all false

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/3520/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        
driver.get("https://leafground.com/radio.xhtml");

WebElement defaultbutton1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'j_idt87:console2\']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]/span"));
WebElement defaultbutton2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'j_idt87:console2\']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[2]/span"));
WebElement defaultbutton3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"j_idt87:console2\"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/span"));
WebElement defaultbutton4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'j_idt87:console2\']/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/div[2]/span"));
        
boolean status1 = defaultbutton1.isSelected();
boolean status2 = defaultbutton2.isSelected();
boolean status3 = defaultbutton3.isSelected();
boolean status4 = defaultbutton4.isSelected();
        
System.out.println(status1);
System.out.println(status2);
System.out.println(status3);
System.out.println(status4);
```

Tried the above code and expecting the value as True for 3 option as it is default selected. But in console all values are returned as false.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it always prints `false` is because selenium won't understand this element as checkbox/radio button. Selenium's `.isSelected` method will mostly only work if the HTML node is `input` and attribute `@type='checkbox'`

In your case, one way you can check if the element is selected or not is by checking the element's `@class` attribute. Check the below code:

```
driver.get("https://leafground.com/radio.xhtml");
WebElement defaultbutton1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_idt87:console2']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]/span"));
WebElement defaultbutton2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_idt87:console2']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[2]/span"));
WebElement defaultbutton3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_idt87:console2']/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/span"));
WebElement defaultbutton4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_idt87:console2']/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/div[2]/span"));
                    
String status1 = defaultbutton1.getAttribute("class");
String status2 = defaultbutton2.getAttribute("class");
String status3 = defaultbutton3.getAttribute("class");
String status4 = defaultbutton4.getAttribute("class");
                    
System.out.println(status1);
System.out.println(status2);
System.out.println(status3);
System.out.println(status4);
            
if (status1.contains("bullet")) {
    System.out.println("Button selected");
} else {
    System.out.println("Button NOT selected");
}
            
if (status2.contains("bullet")) {
    System.out.println("Button selected");
} else {
    System.out.println("Button NOT selected");
}
            
if (status3.contains("bullet")) {
    System.out.println("Button selected");
} else {
    System.out.println("Button NOT selected");
}
            
if (status4.contains("bullet")) {
    System.out.println("Button selected");
} else {
    System.out.println("Button NOT selected");
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c
ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c
ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-bullet ui-c
ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c
Button NOT selected
Button NOT selected
Button selected
Button NOT selected
```

Comment: Thanks. The above worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isSelected()` but only on the INPUT. You are selecting the SPAN with your locators.

```
//*[@id=\'j_idt87:console2\']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]/span
                                                        ^^^^
```

You can even go a step further and get the label for each of the radio buttons by grabbing the ID off the INPUT

```
<input id="j_idt87:console2:0" name="j_idt87:console2" type="radio" value="Option1">
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and then looking for the corresponding LABEL.

```
<label for="j_idt87:console2:0">Chrome</label>
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Once you've got both pieces, you can loop through all INPUTs for a question and print all outputs. Your code is reduced to simply...

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://leafground.com/radio.xhtml");

var radioButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id='j_idt87:console2'] input"));
for (WebElement radioButton : radioButtons) {
    String id = radioButton.getAttribute("id");
    String label = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(MessageFormat.format("label[for=''{0}'']", id))).getText();
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0}: {1}", label, radioButton.isSelected()));
}

driver.quit();
```

The output

```
Chrome: false
Firefox: false
Safari: true
Edge: false
```

If you were going to reuse this, you could put this code into a method where you pass the locator for the INPUT and it prints all labels and selection status.